# Hibernate Regex

Tags: regex, hibernate, hql

I am trying to build an API which can search by HQL regex keywords,

EDITED:
The best way to perform regex search in HQL is to use criteria, Restrictions.like() or Restrictions.ilike().

```
public static List<Object> createQueryAnd(Criteria cri,
        ArrayList<Parameters> list) {

    for (Parameters p : list) {
        String value = (String) p.value;
        if (value.contains("*")) {
            value = value.replace("*", "%");
        } else {
            value += "%";
        }
        Criterion c1 = Restrictions.ilike(p.property, value);
        cri.add(c1);

    }

    return cri.list();
}
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Y is this being voted down? was it a silly question?

Comment: It helped me, thank you! Vote up for you =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HQL does not have regular expressions. If you want to use database provider specific constructs for regular expression, Dialect should be modified. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793159/how-to-use-oracles-regexp-like-in-hibernate-hql) question contains discussion about how to do that with Oracle database.

Comment: Is there any thing specific to postgres dialect?

Comment: You have to depend on functions/operators available in PostgreSQL when extending HQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: Thanks...Does this seem to work: SELECT * from table where regexp_matches(colname, 'lan*'); ?

Comment: No. As said, there is no support for regular expressions in HQL and also not in Hibernate criteria queries. To make it work, you have to implement it (part of implementation being extending Dialect). Also your query seems to be rather SQL than HQL.