# Is There a Way to Search by Phrases and Using Regular Expressions in Hibernate Search?

Tags: hibernate-search

I know the [Hibernate Search 5.5 Reference Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.5/reference/en-US/html_single/) describes the phrase queries at the section **5.1.2.4. Phrase queries**, but that kind of phrase queries only allow slop factors instead of the regular expressions.

Is there a way to allow me in Hibernate Search to search by phrases and using the regular expressions? Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe that HQL has any out of the box support for regular expressions ([ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245453/hibernate-regex)), but you might able to use any regex functionality which your particular DB has ([ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702544/hibernate-regexp-mysql)).

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for your reply and references. Now I am using Hibernate Search and Lucene to do the full-text search. It is my first time to use them and I have not found a way to use HQL together with Hibernate Search and Lucene. It seems Hibernate Search and Lucene provide some API methods and we just use them to do the searches, there seems no interface in them to allow to pass HQL statements like normal Hibernate queries. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `Hibernate Search` isn't related to HQL, it's a much more powerful extension to the query capabilities which you can obtain via  SQL or HQL. Looks like you don't know what it is, you're missing out on a lot of powerful capabilities! I'd suggest to have a look at the linked reference guide.

Comment: @Sanne Thanks for the pointer.  I like SO because I learn something new every day.

Answer (score 3):

Section 5.1.2.4 shows a simple example using Phrase queries using the Hibernate Search DSL.

When you use the DSL you get some help, such as automatic type conversion, so it's the suggested way for most simple use case, however you can bypass the DSL and create any `Lucene Query` using the Lucene APIs, and use the `Query` instance like it was built using the DQL.

For regex queries, see `org.apache.lucene.search.RegexpQuery`.

All Apache Lucene query instances are compatible with Hibernate Search.