# Fetching data with Special Characters from HQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have a search functionality that is implemented on my current project, I am using HQL for the repo method - Everything is okay except searching for special characters for some reason HQL is not escaping it.

```
 @Query("SELECT f FROM Item f WHERE f.id=:id AND f.itemNm LIKE %:itemNm %")
 Item findByItemNm(@Param("itemNm ") String itemNm, @Param("id") Long id);
```

The String search I am sending is

> abc_xyz(YYYYMM[t-2]-YYYYMM[t-1])_[xyz]HU.xlsx

Debugging Steps

Before sending to the Repo - I did replace all the special characters with the following -newsearchString  is the one thatt is being passed to the repo

```
String newsearchString = searchString.replaceAll("(?=[]\\[+&|!(){}^\"~*?:\\\\_])  ", "/");
```

I have also tried it without replacing the special characters- It is not being returned

How do you escape characters in HQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for your problem...It should work for your need.

1) Find and replace all your escape characte, and replaced by "\\"
   Example: [hi]_mysearch should be replaced like ***\\[hi\\]_mysearch***

2) Change your repo query like below

```
 @Query("SELECT f FROM Item f WHERE f.id=:id AND f.itemNm LIKE %:itemNm % escape '\\'")
 Item findByItemNm(@Param("itemNm ") String itemNm, @Param("id") Long id);
```

Answer (score 0):

HQL does not have regular expressions out of the box. You'd have to modify the Dialect for your specific database to add that functionality. ([Oracle example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793159/how-to-use-oracles-regexp-like-in-hibernate-hql))

If you're just trying use like with the `%` wildcard, then you can do the following:

```
String itemNm = "abc_xyz(YYYYMM[t-2]-YYYYMM[t-1])_[xyz]HU.xlsx";
Query q = session.createQuery("from Item where itemNm like :itemNm ";
q.setString("itemNm","%"+itemNm+"%");
```