# Regex Queries without using Native SQL queries - JPA

Tags: java, regex, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data

My question is how to get values from the database (PostgreSQL) **by regex**, BUT not using native SQL queries. 
The only way I found is to use Hibernate Criteria API:

*criteria.add(**Restrictions.sqlRestriction**("name ~ '^(?!" + filter + ")'"));*

But this method also uses SQL. Spring data has query creation functionality but regex search seems to be working only with MongoDb.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

My goal is not depending on native sql queries, use objects instead, and make my project portable for any other databases.

Comment: JPA is doing O-R mapping.  Your queries have to finally be turned into SQL to be executed in the DBMS.  Forget about JPA, ask yourself: how can you retrieve data from PostGres without using SQL and is "portable"?  I don't believe you can do it.

Comment: It is clear that hibernate, spring data and others will use sql queries eventually and there is no other way. I am looking for the functions of these like: someObject.addRegex(String regex).

Comment: `someObject.addRegex(String regex)` means nothing.  What you are looking for is not archievable: There is no **portable** that you can query data from different DBMS without SQL

Comment: Please, have a look:  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

Comment: so?... what you have quoted has nothing to do with your question

Comment: Do you actually mean: not relying on JPA Native Query (or Hibernate SQL Query), and make use of JPQL/HQL?

Comment: It can be HQL, SPEL, the functionality of Spring Data or Hibernate, whatever. The crucial point is not to use native sql query myself. https://gyazo.com/0306809a18069007aa4bb2799444f9e8

Comment: (SPEL is something totally irrelevant here ok?) you have been asking the question in extremely ambiguous way causing a lot of confusion. Go back to your question: first you need to understand SpringData JPA relies on JPA, and Hibernate as JPA impl relies on SQL. Regex matching is never something widely available in different DBMS. If now you just want to use it with HQL for whatever DMBS supporting regex match, you may refer to this question for how to add custom function to Hibernate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793159/how-to-use-oracles-regexp-like-in-hibernate-hql/12976962#12976962

Comment: Then you can make use of `@Query` of Spring data to write "portable" queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with extending Hibernate Dialect class(es) and add your custom methods. Magic really ? :)

Comment: UPDATE : If you are using Spring MVC and you want to get only matches from url params then you can use regex pattern within RequestMapping. for example : @RequestMapping(value = "/e{^\\+?\\d+\$}")