# Accessing REGEXP_LIKE function in CriteriaBuilder

Tags: regex, oracle, criteria-api

I have a multicriteria form and am using CriteriaBuilder to build the sql. For the Local Contact criteria I need to use a regexp_like function in order to search for a numerical string in a string of comma separated numbers, ie search for '234' in a string e.g '1234,2345,6789,234'and it should only return a record with the exact match and not a partial match.

I have tested my regexp_like syntax in Oracle and the pattern I am using works and gives me the result I expect.

The following java code using a simple *like* works (simplified version with only two criteria being taken into account)

```
public List<ExpSessionInfoLightVO> findBySchedulingSearchExperimentsParams(String categoryCode, Integer categoryCounter,
        String expSessionPlaceHolderCategory, Date startsAfterDate, Date startsBeforeDate, Date endsAfterDate, Date endsBeforeDate,
        Long beamlinePk, Long pseudoBeamlinePk, Long runPk, Long scientistPk, String scientistRole, Long localContactPk,
        boolean showHiddenProposals, boolean withIHR) throws Exception {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
    Root<ExpSessionInfoLightVO> esilvo = cq.from(ExpSessionInfoLightVO.class);

    // Constructing list of parameters
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>()

    // Local contact criteria
    if (localContactPk != null && localContactPk > 0) {
        Expression<String> path = esilvo.get("lcPks");
        Predicate localContact = cb.like(path, "%" + MISNumberUtils.toString(localContactPk) + "%");
        predicates.add(localContact);
    }

    // Run criteria
    if (runPk != null && runPk > 0) {
        Predicate beamline = cb.equal(esilvo.get("runNo"), runPk);
        predicates.add(beamline);
    }

    cq.select(esilvo).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
    cq.orderBy(cb.asc(esilvo.get("startDate")));
    System.out.println(em.createQuery(cq).unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString());
    // execute query
    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();

}
```

It generates the following query:

```
select generatedAlias0 from ExpSessionInfoLightVO as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.lcPks like :param0 ) and ( generatedAlias0.runNo=114L ) order by generatedAlias0.startDate asc
```

However if I change the Local Contact criteria code to :

```
if (localContactPk != null && localContactPk > 0) {
        Expression<String> regExpr = cb.literal("(^|\\s|\\w)(" + MISNumberUtils.toString(localContactPk) + ")($|\\s|\\w)");
        Expression<String> path = esilvo.get("lcPks");
        Expression<Boolean> regExprLike = cb.function("regexp_like", Boolean.class, path, regExpr);
        Predicate localContact = cb.equal(regExprLike, 1);
        predicates.add(localContact);
    }
```

I am getting the error 
`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.

Despite following the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793159/how-to-use-oracles-regexp-like-in-hibernate-hql).  I have registered the function as explained :

`public class Oracle10gCustomDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
    public Oracle10gCustomDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("instr", new StandardSQLFunction("instr", IntegerType.INSTANCE));
        registerFunction("regexp_like",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "(case when (regexp_like(?1, ?2)) then 1 else 0 end)"));
    }
}`

and  the dialect appears in the persistence.xml file

```
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
```

I am a novice in java and JPA/Hibernate stuff so would be grateful for any pointers you can give me.
Thanks

Comment: `REGEXP_LIKE` is an Oracle SQL function, and is not known to or part of Hibernate.  If you want to call it, you will need to do so as a native function (e.g. via a raw query).

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that Oracle SQL does not support calling of functions with Boolean parameters or returns and that moreover REGEXP_LIKE is a condition and not a function.

In order to get around this I have used instead REGEXP_INSTR, and have registered it like this:

```
public class Oracle10gCustomDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
public Oracle10gCustomDialect() {
    super();
    registerFunction("regexp_instr", new StandardSQLFunction("regexp_instr", IntegerType.INSTANCE));
```

and changed my code to

```
        if (localContactPk != null && localContactPk > 0) {
        Expression<String> regExpr = cb.literal("(^|\\s|\\w)(" + MISNumberUtils.toString(localContactPk) + ")($|\\s|\\w)");
        Expression<String> path = esilvo.get("lcPks");
        Expression<Integer> regExprInstr = cb.function("regexp_instr", Integer.class, path, regExpr);
        Predicate localContact = cb.gt(regExprInstr, 0);

        predicates.add(localContact);}
```

and the query works fine.